# I am facing a problem deploying my Laravel project to subdomain in the server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am facing a problem deploying my Laravel project to a subdomain in the server.

I keep getting this error:

> There is no existing directory at "/Users/../../../storage/logs" and it’s not buildable: Permission denied.

I did exactly as described in this video: [How to upload laravel to Cpanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Rbpb56esyg)  to deploy my laravel project to the subdomain.

However, I keep getting this error:

> There is no existing directory at "/Users/../../../storage/logs" and it’s not buildable: Permission denied.

To solve this error I did:

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

then *compress* the project again and *re-upload* it to the server.

However I got another error which is:

> 500 Whoops, something went wrong on our servers

I expect the laravel project to work properly in the subdomain.

Comment: Did you give 777 permission to storage directory ?

Comment: Could you print out the log in storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: @VinodJoshi Yes I changed the storage folder permissions from the server from (755) to (777) then refresh the page but (there is no existing directory....) error is still showing)

Comment: @makamuevans how can I print the log file of the project which is located in the server?

Comment: Do you have ssh access of your server ?

Comment: @VinodJoshi yes I do have ssh access but i have never used it.

Comment: Which os you have installed on your server? If its ubuntu then you can use this https://hectacode.com/how-to-install-laravel-5-8-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/  skip first step

Comment: @VinodJoshi Thank you so much for your help. I solved the problem by doing these 2 steps: 1) go to Bootstrap/cache and delete config.php file after that
2) goto storage/logs and delete all log files

Comment: @makamuevans Thank you so much for your help. I solved the problem by doing these 2 steps: 1) go to Bootstrap/cache and delete config.php file after that 2) goto storage/logs and delete all log files

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing these 2 steps:
1) go to Bootstrap/cache and delete config.php file.
2) goto storage/logs and delete all log files.